# Add new records to "database" and update existing records that have a change. How to add data to the correct rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been piecing together a script that will take a row of data from all spreadsheets in my drive that contain `X` in the file name and were updated within the last day, and add that row to a primary "database" spreadsheet. Everything works great. The issue I have is that I'd like to add two columns to each row that is being added or updated to record the original sheet url and the current date/time.

I'm already able to access both the url value (`urls` for all or `url` for each) as well as the date/time (`now`), but I can't figure out where in my script to add them so they appear in my final output.

Below is the current code. How can I resolve this?

```
  var urls = [];
  var originalSheetName = 'sheetNameToCopy';
  var now = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  var yesterday = yesterday.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "'+yesterday+'" and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" and title contains "X"'); 
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    urls.push([file.getUrl()]);
    } 

  for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i){
      var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urls[i][0]);
      var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('ADD TARGET SHEET URL HERE').getSheetByName('Summary'); //ADD TARGET SHEET URL
      
  const OFFSET = 1;
  const data = targetSheet.getRange(1 + OFFSET, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow() - OFFSET, 20).getValues();
  var url = urls[i];
  const values = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(originalSheetName).getRange('A3:T3').getValues().filter(row => {
      if (row[0] === '') return false;
      const index = data.findIndex(r => r[0] === row[0]);
      if (index === -1) return true;
      data[index] = row.slice();
      return false;
    });
    
    targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length + values.length, data[0].length).setValues(data.concat(values));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unshift` or `push` and add those two columns in front or back of the `values` array:

It will look like this :-

```
values.forEach(r=>r.unshift(now , url )) // will add Date and Url at Front
```

or

```
values.forEach(r=>r.push(now , url )) // will add Date and Url at back
```

Use any of the approach mentioned above before you're setting values, like this:-

```
values.forEach(r=>r.unshift(now , url ))
targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length + values.length, data[0].length).setValues(data.concat(values));
```

Reference:

[unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. It just returned an empty array...

Comment: I have been able to successfully add the values to the url and now values using `.map` as follows: `targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length + values.length, data[0].length).setValues(data.concat(values.map(function(row){return row.concat(url,now)})));`

It works great on the first import but on the second run through it also gives me this exception: Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 20 but the range has 22.

Comment: What you should do is declare blank array, and in the for loop push values in it, and when you get information from all the sheet and for loop completes and than paste that array value using setValues.